# Take is not a function : Angular 7 | Observable.take throws runtime error

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error, angularfire2, take

I am building a shopping cart and I have used a shopping cart service in which I am assigning the quantities to a product/adding a product to the cart. Is there any other way than to use take for getting the first instance of the observable item$ ?

I am importing the take operator correctly yet it keeps giving me runtime error. If I don't use take, then the quantity assigned is some random integer instead of 1.

I am getting the below error on using take() on an observable in the below code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Product } from '../app/models/product';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';//tried this one too
import { take } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/take';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }


  private getCart(cartId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);
  }
  private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;

  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) { 
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.db.object('/shopping-carts/'+cartId+'/items/'+product.$key);
    item$.take(1).subscribe(item=>{
      if(item.$exists()) item$.update({quantity : item.quantity + 1});
      else item$.set({product : product , quantity : 1 });
    });
  }

}




Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: item$.take is not a function. (In 'item$.take(1)', 'item$.take' is undefined) http://localhost:4200/main.js:1581:35 step@http://localhost:4200/main.js:1534:27 fulfilled@http://localhost:4200/main.js:1506:62 onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46707:39 run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2483:49 http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3217:37 onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46698:43 runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2533:57 drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2940:42 invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2845:40 invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3885:20 globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3911:27
resolvePromise — zone.js:814
(anonymous function) — zone.js:724
fulfilled — products.component.ts:11
onInvoke — core.js:14143
run — zone.js:138
(anonymous function) — zone.js:872
onInvokeTask — core.js:14134
runTask — zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue — zone.js:595
invokeTask — zone.js:500
invokeTask — zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback — zone.js:1566
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 issues i notice are:

1. Import - should be : `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';`
2. You should use `pipe` : in your case:

   `item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)`

Read more about it on [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html)

Comment: I used a pipe too but it then gives a compilation error.

Comment: You should remove all the other imports with `take`, and use just this one and make sure your if you are importing `Observable` it should be `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
`